# Eliminating the need for the global keyword in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, global-variables

I am making a simple PHP application with an MVC design. All of the requests are being sent to `index.php` and then routed to the appropriate controller. Because all of the requests go through `index.php`, I want to create some objects there and be able to use them globally, regardless of which controller handles the request. Namely, these objects are of type `User`, `ErrorHandler`, and `Database`.

Having a global `User` class, for example, allows any controller to check if the user is logged in by checking `$user->loggedIn` (or something like that) where `$user` is instantiated in `index.php`.

Here is what I am describing in code:

```
// index.php:

<?php
    include('lib/User.php');

    $user = new User();

    // other stuff that index.php needs to do, perhaps route to FooController
?>

// FooController.php:

<?php
    class FooController {
        function __construct() {
            global $user;        

            if ($user->loggedIn) {
                // do whatever
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is just random code I just typed up so please excuse any stupid errors -- but I hope you get the idea. This code will work, but the `global $user;` line must be included in every function inside `FooController.php`.

This will get annoying when every function must have three `global` statements, one for `User`, `ErrorHandler`, and `Database`. Is there a better way to go about this, while preserving my MVC design?

Comment: You can use several patterns in order to achieve this. For instance, take a look at the Singleton, Multiton and Registry patterns. The last one may be your best option for a replacement of global variables.

Comment: Why you don't pass $user to the constructor of your controller?

Comment: class FooController extends user{... ?

Comment: @Macmade, a Singleton is just a global in disguise.

Comment: @GolezTrol No... Usually the PHP singleton pattern is implemented using a class static variable for the shared instance. So no global here...

Comment: I know, but you still have a single instance that can be reached only through that central point. Whether it's a global variable, or a static in a singleton class, it's pretty much the same effect. I meant to say that replacing globals by singletons doesn't do very much for the general structure of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
class BaseController
{
    public $user, $db, $errors;

    function __construct()
    {
         global $user, $db, $errors;

         $this->user = $user;
         $this->db = $db;
         $this->errors = $errors;
    }
}
```

Every controller extends the BaseController (which has some abstract functions as well, this is just an example of a BaseController which solves this specific problem). This way I only had to use `global` once, and then I could use the user, db, and error handler instances across every controller by simply calling `parent::__construct()` in each controller's constructor and then referring to them by `$this->user`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You hardly ever need `global`. Just don't create globals.

First. There's such a thing as parameters, for instance:

```
function __construct($user)
{ ... }
```

Now, you can call:

```
$controller = new MyController($user);
```

.. and you don't need 'global'.

Even better if your controller is, well, a controller that manages the flow of your entire application. In that case, you will only need to pass it a few classes, for instance a database class and maybe a parser for input. If you don't care about that, you can make the controller instantiate a database class and parser itself. You can always refactor that part if you need to support multiple types of databases and multiple kinds of input.

Then, those database can be set as a property of the controller. Each next class will know of this controller. You can set the controller instance in a global, or even better, pass it in the constructor of other classes, so they don't depend on globals at all.

If those classes don't need a controller, but just need a database, you can pass the database class only. That will make those classes even more independent from the controller and from any globals, so you can reuse them very easily in other applications, provided that the database itself doesn't depend (directly or indirectly) on the controller either.

Take a look at frameworks like Kohana. They solve these problems pretty well, although there's always room for improvement.

Comment: You can also set a property in the class `public $User;` and then set that in your constructor `$this->User = $user`.  Then anywhere you need the User class... `$this->User`.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what I wrote.

Comment: I don't want to send $user, $database, and $errorhandler (or whatever) to every controller I make. That is the point... the point isn't necessarily eliminating global variables. It is more about having to instantiate the variables once and having them be accessible in any controller without having to do other stuff (whether that be using `global`, retrieving singleton instances, or passing parameters).

Comment: If you put them in an appcontext (or whatever you want to call it), you only need to pass that appcontext to the controllers. Of course you can make that context a global of singleton too, but that makes all controllers depend on that global, making your code less reusable. If all your controllers inherit from a controller base class, you can pass the appcontext to the constructor in that base class and set a property in the base controller. Every descendant will have that property available. It's easy to pass one or two variables when you create an object, and you gain lots of structure.